# CTC loss for keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, ctc

How to use tensorflows CTC loss function in keras?

I have tried doing it like this:

```
def ctc_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return(tf.nn.ctc_loss(y_pred, y_true, 64, 
         preprocess_collapse_repeated=False, ctc_merge_repeated=False, 
         time_major=True))
```

The model used is:

```
def build_model():
    encoder_input = Input(shape=(512,64), name='encoder_in')
    x = Bidirectional(GRU(64, implementation=2, 
                      return_sequences=True),merge_mode='concat')(encoder_input)
    x = GRU(128, implementation=2, return_sequences=True)(x)
    x = LSTM(64, implementation=2, return_sequences=True)(x) 
    model = Model(inputs=encoder_input,outputs=x)
    #model.load_weights('Tuned.h5')
    model.compile(loss=ctc_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

But i keep getting an error:

```
File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\tensorflow-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\ctc_ops.py", line 139, in ctc_loss
    raise TypeError("Expected labels (first argument) to be a SparseTensor")
TypeError: Expected labels (first argument) to be a SparseTensor
```

How can I fix this? How can I convert the output tensor to sparse?

Comment: Try using `K.ctc_label_dense_to_sparse(y,label_lengths)`, where K is `import keras.backend as K`. -- See here: https://keras.io/backend/#ctc_label_dense_to_sparse

Comment: That is to convert my labels to sparse format. But my program crashes at model.compile only before even checking the labels. If I use `ctc_batch_cost ` in keras.io/backend/#ctc_batch_cost i cannot understand whether the input length will be the full sequence length which is (time_steps * num_classes) or just num_classes

Comment: Model compile does check the loss functions, and the message seems to be exactly this: it's expecting the labels to be sparse. It's worth trying.

Comment: e, why not try ctc_label_dense_to_sparse ?